# How can I update mapped fields only when a condition is satisfied?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

In my Symfony2 application I created a custom form to edit objects of a `User` class. Users have a `password` property which contains a hash of the user's password. For obvious reasons, I do not want to echo this property's value into a field. However, I want a password field on my form so that when editing a user it is possible to change the user's password.

This password field should behave as follows:

- <s>If the user has a password set, then the field should contain `********`.</s>
- <s>If the user has no password set, then the field should be empty.</s>
- (It turns out the previous two points are impossible to achieve with my current architecture, so instead I am going for:) When the page is loaded, the field should be empty, regardless of whether the user has a password set.
- If the field is posted with content, then the user's password should be set to the hashed value of the field.
- If the field is posted empty, the user's password should not be changed and, more importantly, not cleared.

I thought of implementing this with a custom data transformer. However, the data transformer does not provide me with a way to skip updating the user's `password` property when the password field is posted empty.

Where do I need to extend the framework to add custom logic deciding which fields should be updated?

### UPDATE

This is the legacy code I am trying to replace:

```
/* SomeController.php */

$pass = $request->get('password');
if (strlen($pass) >= 5 && strlen($pass) <= 16) {
    $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
    $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
    $password = $encoder->encodePassword($pass, $user->getSalt());

    $user->setPassword($password);
}
```

I can live with removing the string length checks. All I want to check is whether something has been entered.

As you can see, I can not simply move this code to a data transformer as it needs to access the `$user` which is the user we are currently editing. I don't think it is a good idea to create a service providing this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with for now but I am not happy with the solution as it involves custom form processing in the controller. However, so far this is the only way I have found to make it work.

My form class adds an unmapped field for the user's password:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('username')
            ->add('displayName')
            ->add('password', 'password', ['mapped' => false]);
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'MyCompany\MyBundle\Entity\User'));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

This field is then processed manually in my controller class:

```
class UserAdminController extends Controller {
    public function editUserAction($userId, Request $request) {
        $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyCompanyMyBundle:User')->findOneById($userId);

        $form = $this->createForm('user', $user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $newPassword = $form['password']->getData();
            if ($newPassword !== "") {
                $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
                $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
                $password = $encoder->encodePassword($newPassword, $user->getSalt());

                $user->setPassword($password);
            }
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->render(
            "MyCompanyMyBundle:Admin/Management/User:Edit.html.php",
            [
                "form"  => $form->createView()
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just insert a control directly into your entity method and use data transformer (as you have insight)

So your entity will be

```
class User
{
  //some properties and methods here

  public function setPassword($pwd = null) {
    if (null !== $pwd) {
      $this->password = //do actions here like hash or whatever
    }
    //don't update the password
  }
}
```

---

If you want to take advantage only of DataTransformers, you could still do what you need that way

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class PasswordTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
  private $ci;

  public function __construct(ContainerInterface $ci) {
    $this->ci = $ci;
  }
  //...
  public function reverseTransform($form_password) {
    if (!$form_password) {
      //return password already stored
      return $this->ci->get('security.context')
                      ->getToken()
                      ->getUser()
                      ->getPassword();
    }
  }
}
```

Of course you need to inject `service_container` service into you data transformer (or better, you should inject it into your form type's selector and pass to DataTransformer constructor as follows:

```
services:
your.bundle.password_selector_type:
    class: Your\Bundle\Form\Type\PasswordSelectorType
    arguments: ["@security.context"]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: password_selector_type }
```

Comment: This is a possible solution but I am not too happy with it because IMHO it is not the entity's job to decide whether a password should be set or not. This should be handled by the GUI. Also this prevents me from implementing a "clear password" button.

Comment: @Chris: what you're saying is true but not at all. I mean, if the behaviour would be "consistent" in all the bundle, it would be quite good to implement that piece of logic directly into entity itself, preventing you from mistakes due to "control code forgetfulness". Of course if the logic is ruled by other aspects, it couldn't be inserted into entity itself (it's clear).

Comment: @Chris: take a look at my update, that should be more suitable to your needs

Comment: Thanks, this is what I will likely go with. But I am still not entirely happy because this means that I need to read the user in order not to overwrite the password. IMHO it should not be necessary to know the current password in order to figure out whether it should be set. But this is close enough for now.

Comment: @Chris: nothing else came in my mind. When and if you have a better idea/approach, please share with me (us) :)

Comment: Actually, it turns out that in my case the injection as you suggested is not sufficient as I also need to access some variables from the controller which are not provided by DI (see updated question).

Answer (score 1):

For the form part, you should take a look a this widget.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html

It provides an easy way to ask and treat confirmation on a field (it also hide values with stars when you set type to password).

```
$builder->add('password', 'repeated', array(
'type' => 'password',
'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
'options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'password-field')),
'required' => true,
'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password'),
'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password')));
```

It will check first and second options to be equal. If that's the case then your form will be considered as valid. Otherwise, invalid_message will be displayed and first field will set to the content typed by user while confirmation field (second option) will be emptied.

You can add some logic afterwards like hashing the password to finally persist your entity. (Extracting it in a form handler would be a good practice).

Comment: I don't really know where I should transform the password afterwards. From looking at https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/3919 it seems that form handlers are not a recommended way of doing this.

Comment: You'll still have to split validation and treatment. FormHandler is the way I used to do it, but more generally, you can think of FormHandler as services (it's what I do in most of my app).
This way, you can declare a service which compute the hash and set it to the user who can be retrieved from secutiry context (you can inject it from service declaration).

Comment: Yes, but where and how? I am having a hard time finding the right extension points for these tasks.

Comment: Well, the thing is that I can not get the user from the security context as the controller is the only one who knows which user I am trying to edit. Note that this is about editing users which are not the currently logged in user.

Comment: Then you should use a service which contains a function taking the form or the user and the password taken from the form (I would prefer the last possibility)
This function would then be called one the form has been successfully validated and will hash the password, set it to the user and then persist the user.
Otherwise you can get inspired by FOSUserBundle. But it would be a little bit more complexe to setup.

Comment: But when and where would I get and invoke this service? I would prefer not doing it in the controller because then I need to remember to do it whenever I use this form.

Comment: The other solution is then to use DataTransformer as suggested by @DonCallisto. But you can do it more properly.

See the doc for further details:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

Comment: The problem remains that I can not have the user I am editing automatically injected in my data transformer. This means I could not use my custom form class as a service and I could not use my data transformer as a service.